# Screen access restrictions data modeling approach

Tags: architecture, language-agnostic, data-modeling

I have a program that has usernames/passwords. Each user has a "security level," of which, right now (because we're still in the early stages of the app), there's two options: "Administrator" and "Associate." On the software-level, there are hardcoded restrictions for Associate-level accounts and no restrictions for Administrator-level accounts.

However, we need more variety than this. Some users need access to only one screen in the app, some need access to several, etc. There are a lot of different options. These are the solutions I've thought of:

1. **Mutliple security levels with hardcoded restrictions.** - I think this would be the easiest, but I don't think it's a great idea, because then the list of security levels would seem too ad-hoc. I.E., I would be given a need "this user needs to see screen x, y, and z but nothing else" so we just code a new security level and hard-code those restirctions. Worse, each hardcoded security level would need to be explained or else the administrator who is changing the levels will have no idea what he's changing it to.
2. **A "custom" security level with a screen allowing the administrator to select which screens each custom account can see.** - This is my ideal approach but I'm trying to conceptualize this on a database level.

For #2 I'd have to create two tables I think:

```
Table: custom_user_permission
   | user_id | screen_id |
 --|---------|-----------|
 1 |      5  |        1  |
 2 |      5  |        2  |
 3 |      5  |        3  |
 4 |     12  |        1  |
 5 |      4  |        2  |
```

and another:

```
 Table: screen:

   | id (PK) | screen_name |
 --|---------|------__-----|
 1 |      1  |   Screen x  |
 2 |      2  |   Screen y  |
 3 |      3  |   Screen z  |
```

I don't know how this would be interpreted on the software level, though... Maybe instead of the 2nd table it would be better to define which `screen_id` applies to which screen on the software level. This will make "screen_id" an arbitrary integer on the database making it difficult to read.

1. **A mix of 1 and 2** - Perhaps allowing the Administrators to create their own security level profiles. But that's like the worst of both in terms of complexity. :)

Anyone have advice? My thought is that this would be a pretty common problem, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is depends on you system complexity.
If the system has not so much screens (less than 20) and there is no situation when requirements can be modified by client you can hardcode all the rights.

For the second variant you can implement [role based security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control).
Example of tables structure:

```
ROLES (ID, ROLENAME)
USERS (ID, USERNAME)
USER_TO_ROLES(ID_USER, ID_ROLE)
SCREENS (ID, SCREEN_NAME)
ACCESS_RIGHTS(ID_ROLE, ID_SCREEN, RIGHT(no access/readonly/....))
```

Every screen paint himself according to current user roles and access_rights, connected with them.

Another variant (better for my opinion) is change SCREENS with actions.

```
ROLES (ID, ROLENAME)
USERS (ID, USERNAME)
USER_TO_ROLES(ID_USER, ID_ROLE)
ACTION (ID, ACTION_NAME)
ACCESS_RIGHTS(ID_ROLE, ID_ACTION, RIGHT(no access/readonly/....))
```

The security core module have to decide if user can execute some action. The security check have to be made before every action invocation (it can be realized with AOP technique). This way you can create a security screen where superusers will gave the access rights for some kind of roles and associate user with some set of roles.

Comment: Yes this is what I've been thinking as well. Except for two things: 1) I don't think I need to store screen information on the database level. I can just store a `screen_id` and figure out what each ID references on the software level. 2) your data normalization seems excessive. No need to have a user_to_roles entity as that can just be stored on the user entity (`ROLE(ID, NAME)` `USER(ID, USERNAME, ROLE_ID)`). Also, the buttons that are used to invoke the screens will simply be disabled if the users are not permitted access.